# How do I build a simple Android project written in Scala?

Tags: android, scala

How do I build a simple Android project written entirely in Scala? Yet I haven't found any easy out-of-the-box working solution.

Edit:
Do you seriously consider creating a 'Hello, World'  app as being too 'broad' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the android project that I developed for fun [happyheal project](https://github.com/pamu/happyheal)

```
git clone git@github.com:pamu/happyheal.git
```

do `sbt run` in the project folder to run

```
sbt run
```

**sbt run output**

```
[info] Creating proguard cache: proguard-cache-f9ccaeb3cdc9261016b1e8ec5127c562a9817b0d.jar
[info] Generating dex, incremental=false, multidex=false
[info] dex method count: 35977
[info] Packaged: happyheal-debug-unaligned.apk (2.50MB)
[info] Debug package does not need signing: happyheal-debug-unaligned.apk
[info] zipaligned: happyheal-debug.apk
[info] Installing to **** (4f569f68)...
[info] [happyheal-debug.apk] Install finished: 2.50MB in 7.37s. 348.03KB/s
[info] Running on **** (4f569f68)...
[info] Starting: Intent { cmp=com.happyheal.happyhealapp/.ui.wizard.WizardActivity }
[success] Total time: 86 s, completed 20 Sep, 2016 2:38:47 AM
```

Comment: Hey, I know that one, thanks, I got tons of conflicts while trying to build this though :(

Comment: @HappyTorturer ... edited the answer .. please check. this works and builds with errors

Comment: @HappyTorturer Hope this helps... all the best

Comment: @HappyTorturer fixed compile errors .. pull changes, do `sbt clean` and `sbt run` to run the project

Comment: thank you! I'll check this out and let you know if everything goes fine.

Comment: I have tried to sbt run your project, but got a compilation error:
[error] .../IdeaProjects/wrk/src/scala/projects/android/happyheal/src/main/java/com/happyheal/happyhealapp/commons/ui/AutoFitRecyclerView.java:12: class AutofitRecyclerView is public, should be declared in a file named AutofitRecyclerView.java. It has already been declared in that file as public though.

Comment: git pull origin master ... Pull the code ... I have fixed the error long time ago

Comment: guess not, git states: "already up to date". smth is still wrong...

Comment: @HappyTorturer https://github.com/pamu/happyheal/commits/master  check the last commit ... which fixes the above error

Comment: @HappyTorturer if the problem persists .. delete the local project dir and clone it again

Comment: I cloned three times, the behavior remained the same. Here's my log: http://pastebin.com/EMVjbMUp

Comment: @HappyTorturer fixed it .. please pull now

Comment: @HappyTorturer is the problem persistent ?

Comment: yes, got the same error

Comment: why don't you fix it  .. yourself ... Change the file name `AutoFitRec‌​yclerView.java` to `AutofitRec‌​yclerView.java` .. notice `f` is lower case in second one

Comment: I see, many files involved, writing replacement script

Comment: @HappyTorturer here is the file .. whose name has to be changed happyheal/src/main/java/com/happyheal/happyhealapp/commons/ui/AutoFitRecyclerView.java:

Comment: replaced contents with AutoFitRecyclerView instead. :) successfully builds http://pastebin.com/FVuMfZPw thank you!

Comment: one more question. Is it possible to setup this project for Intellij or Android Studio? I've tried both but ended fighting with endless painful errors of type "No resource found", "Unable to resolve style" etc. though I specified the path to resources correctly in Facets>Structure, invalidated caches, etc. Even after I got rid of unresolved references, the next thing I got was a compilation errors of target/ files like "BuildConfig and R classes are duplicate", "class R and object R should be defined into the same file, etc. Is there a way to setup Intellij for this project?